# AS3 bytearray in C#

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, flash, arrays

I'm trying to port an AS3 function's code to C#.

Using C# I want to send an AMF request which contains a bytearray similar to how this AS3 function shown below does it.

```
public static function serialize(param1:Object) : ByteArray
  {
     var _loc2_:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
     _loc2_.writeObject(param1);
     return _loc2_;
  }
```

I recorded this array in an AMF request using Charles web debugger and I got this:

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAa1T.png)

```
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
```

How can I get this same bytearray result with C#. I want to be able to send AMF request using C# code only.

cheers, 
Niklas

Comment: yeah i just want to send exactly the same object using c#. i dont want to change it or anything. just sending exactly the same

Comment: Also I hope you understand that the input parameter in that function is type `Object` which in AS3 is a table of entries. See **[this guide](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/associative-arrays.html)**. Also for AMF check the **[format specifications](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/amf/pdf/amf-file-format-spec.pdf)** to understand what bytes you should be making. The **[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format)** might help also . Make your C# version from those guides not decompiled code.

Comment: already tried to build upon this but because im german and my english isnt the best i didnt get the result which i wanted with this

Comment: Firstly, my mistake Charles bytes are okay I was checking them wrong way. Secondly, what exactly is the problem...? If you have a HEX Editor, just put your bytes in there to see what it looks like (entries). You can download a free one (on Win PC, there is **[HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/downloads.php)**). Look at your bytes there and check the **[Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format)** to follow its structure. Read from section **AMF0** up to first Hex / ASCII example shown. Thats all you need.

Comment: oh man.. im absultely the sillyest guy ive ever met. the libary which i use to send amf request using c# already ported the as3 byte array class..

Comment: No worries. We are all learning everyday. Is this issue solved now?.

Comment: yeah, thank you, but new problem are already comming, but i better create a new thread ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [BinaryFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to serialize an object, along with a [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) to write the serialization result to a `byte[]`.

Comment: can you write it a little bit more detailed?

Answer (score 0):

To serialize this you need an fluorinefx libray. Your code has to have an FluorineFx.AMF3 lib imported.
To serialize that code you need to do code like this:

```
using FluorineFx.AMF3;
   public static ByteArray serialize(Object param1)
   ByteArray BA = new ByteArray();
   for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        BA.WriteObject
   } 
   return BA;
}
```

You can keep the *loc2* name from the MovieStarPlanet script if you want.